# Extract string within triple quotes in hive using regexp_extract function

Tags: hive

I have a string column in hive table as

```
"""hello:world"""
"""abc:|:def"""
```

I would like to extract only the text within the triple quotes, as

```
hello:world
abc:|:def
```

How can I use regexp_extract function in Hive to do it ?

I am trying,

```
select '"""hello:world"""' as in , regexp_extract('"""hello:world"""','""".*."""' , 0) as out ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `regexp_replace` and `regexp_extract`. For `regexp_extract`, the solution assumes the string pattern is consistent.

```
select regexp_replace(col,'"',''),regexp_extract(col,'"""(.*)"""',1)
from tbl
```